# How to count records from database using VB.NET ?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have the code below:

```
 Dim ds As New DataSet
 Dim sda As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
 Dim sSQL As String
 Dim strCon As String

 sSQL = " .... MY QUERY HERE .... "

 strCon = appBase.dbConnString

 sda = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sSQL, strCon)
 sda.Fill(ds, "MY TABLE FROM DB")


 dgRecordsContent.DataSource = ds.Tables("MY TABLE FROM DB")
 dgRecordsContent.DataBind()

 dgRecordsContent.Visible = True

 dbConn.Close()
```

How can I programatically count the number of rows from the datagrid that I'm showing the values in?

Comment: `Fill` is a method returning the number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the `DataTable` being filled doesn't already contain any rows, you can get the count using:

```
int count = sda.Fill(ds, "MY TABLE FROM DB")
```

Otherwise you can access the rows in the `DataTable` using:

```
int count = ds.Tables("MY TABLE FROM DB").Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim ds As New DataSet
 Dim sda As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
 Dim sSQL As String
 Dim strCon As String

 sSQL = " .... MY QUERY HERE .... "

 strCon = appBase.dbConnString

 sda = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sSQL, strCon)
 Dim num_rows=sda.Fill(ds, "MY TABLE FROM DB")

 MessageBox.Show(num_rows.ToString())  

 dgRecordsContent.DataSource = ds.Tables("MY TABLE FROM DB")
 dgRecordsContent.DataBind()

 dgRecordsContent.Visible = True

 dbConn.Close()
```

Please Check This Edit @Emi